# how to pass model from @html.partial

Tags: asp.net-mvc, razor

below is my cshtml code

ive used IEnumerable in  the main view and and single model object in partial view

im doing CRUD operation ...each row has edit/details/delete buttons

```
@model IEnumerable<jQuery_CRUD.DAL.User>
@foreach (var item in Model)
    {
        <tr>
            <td>
                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Name)
            </td>
            <td>
                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Address)
            </td>
            <td>
                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.ContactNo)
            </td>
            <td>
                @Html.ActionLink("Edit", "Edit", new { id = item.UserId }, new { @class = "modal-with-form btn btn-default" ,href = "#modalEdit" }) |
                @Html.ActionLink("Details", "Details", new { id = item.UserId }, new { @class = "modal-with-form btn btn-default", href = "#modalDetails" }) |
                @Html.ActionLink("Delete", "Delete", new { id = item.UserId }, new { @class = "modal-with-form btn btn-default", href = "#modalDelete" })             



                <div id="modalEdit" class="modal-block modal-block-primary mfp-hide">
                    @Html.Partial("Edit", item)
                </div>

                <div id="modalDetails" class="modal-block modal-block-primary mfp-hide">
                    @Html.Partial("Details", item)
                </div>


                <div id="modalDelete" class="modal-block modal-block-primary mfp-hide">
                    @Html.Partial("Delete", item)
                </div>




            </td>
        </tr>
```

clicking on edit/details shows information only for the first row in the table

the model in the partial view i used is

```
@model jQuery_CRUD.DAL.User
```

HOw do i overcome this

Answer (score 0):

That's because you're re-using the same `id` attribute for each `item` in the table while element `id` should be unique.

Use the `item.UserId` to assign a unique `id` for each:

```
@Html.ActionLink("Edit", "Edit", new { id = item.UserId }, new { href = "#modalEdit" + item.UserId }) |
@Html.ActionLink("Details", "Details", new { id = item.UserId }, new { href = "#modalDetails" + item.UserId }) |
@Html.ActionLink("Delete", "Delete", new { id = item.UserId }, new { href = "#modalDelete" + item.UserId })

<div id="modalEdit@(item.UserId)" class="modal-block modal-block-primary mfp-hide">
  @Html.Partial("Edit", item)
</div>

<div id="modalDetails@(item.UserId)" class="modal-block modal-block-primary mfp-hide">
  @Html.Partial("Details", item)
</div>

<div id="modalDelete@(item.UserId)" class="modal-block modal-block-primary mfp-hide">
  @Html.Partial("Delete", item)
</div>
```

Comment: tat doesnt work all three action links share the same id

Comment: @naveen, No. If you append `item.UserId` to each (as demonstrated in the answer), you'll get a unique id.

Comment: all the the three actionlinks belong to the same row @haim770

Comment: i actually had problem somewhere else

Comment: can u help me in this??? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41357561/partial-view-renders-as-full-view-on-validation-fail