# partial view renders as full view on validation fail

Tags: asp.net-mvc, razor

my controller

```
public ActionResult Create()
    {
        return PartialView();
    }

    //
    // POST: /User/Create

    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Create(User user)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            db.User.Add(user);
            db.SaveChanges();
            TempData["Message"] = "Data has been saved successfully!";
            return RedirectToAction("Index");
        }

        return View(user);
    }
```

my view

```
   <div class="row">



                     @Html.ActionLink("Create New", "Create", null, new { @class = "modal-with-form btn btn-default", href = "#modalForm" })

                    <!-- Modal Form -->


                    <div id="modalForm" class="modal-block modal-block-primary mfp-hide">


                            @Html.Partial("Create", new jQuery_CRUD.DAL.User())

                    </div>
     </div>
```

my partial view

```
   @using (Ajax.BeginForm("Create", "User", null, new AjaxOptions { UpdateTargetId = "modalForm", InsertionMode = InsertionMode.Replace }))
  {


    <section class="panel">
    <header class="panel-heading">
        <h2 class="panel-title">Create</h2>
    </header>
    <div class="panel-body">


        <div class="form-group mt-lg">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Name, new { @class = "col-sm-3 control-label" })

            <div class="col-sm-9">
                @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.Name, new {  name = "name", @class = "form-control", placeholder = "Type your name..."})
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Name)

            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Address, new { @class = "col-sm-3 control-label" })

            <div class="col-sm-9">
                @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.Address, new { name = "address", @class = "form-control", placeholder = "Type your Address..." })
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Address)

            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.ContactNo, new { @class = "col-sm-3 control-label" })

            <div class="col-sm-9">
                @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.ContactNo, new { name = "contactno", @class = "form-control", placeholder = "Type your Contact No..." })
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.ContactNo)

            </div>
        </div>

    </div>
    <footer class="panel-footer">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-12 text-right">


                <input type="submit" value="Create" class="btn btn-primary"  />
                <button class="btn btn-default modal-dismiss" id="btnCancel">Cancel</button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </footer>

</section>   


}
```

when i click the button , modal pops up,upon validation fail on post action, the view returns to full view. where could be the problem????..

i'm new to mvc help me with this..

Answer (score 0):

Add in the beginning of your partial view

```
{
   Layout = null;
}
```

And return partialView in Validation Error not View

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Create(User user)
{
    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        db.User.Add(user);
        db.SaveChanges();
        TempData["Message"] = "Data has been saved successfully!";
        return RedirectToAction("Index");
    }

    return PartialView(user);
}
```

Comment: I Edit my answer, can you try it and tell me the result

Comment: Can you tell me what is your exact problem again ? and what is the name of your main view

Comment: main view name is Index.cshtml......im doing crud operation....i use modal bootstrap popup to create data....clicking on the create new button opens up modal with my partial view....modal closes on successful validation and data is inserted into the table....but on validation fail, the validation error should be shown within the modal popup....but instead the modal popup closes and my partial view renders as full view and shows the validation error